# CUDA Object copy from device to host

Tags: object, cuda, memcpy

I'm trying to copy an object back from the device to host, and it works, but if the object contains a pointer to something i can't find the right way of calling cudaMemcpy.

This is a simplified code to show what i'm trying to do. The cudaMemcpy returns with cudaSuccess but the temp variable stays "empty".

```
class A {
public:
    int *s;
};

__global__ void MethodA(A *a) {
    printf("%d\n", a->s[2]);
}

int main() {
    A *a = new A();
    int asd[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    a->s = asd;
    A *d_a;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, sizeof(A));
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int * temp;
    cudaError e;
    e = cudaMalloc((void**)&temp, sizeof(int) * 5);
    e = cudaMemcpy(temp, a->s, sizeof(int) * 5, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    e = cudaMemcpy(&(d_a->s), &temp, sizeof(int*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    MethodA << <1, 1 >> > (d_a);

    cudaMemcpy(a, d_a, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    e = cudaMemcpy(&temp, a->s, sizeof(int) * 5, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    a->s = temp;

    cudaFree(d_a);
    delete(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
e = cudaMemcpy(&(d_a->s), &temp, sizeof(int*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

`d_a` is a pointer to a device object, you cannot dereference it on the host.
You'll have to first copy `s` to the device, then create an object of type `A` on the host which has a pointer to the device copy of `s`, and then copy this object on the device.

This is a known issue with CUDA, and happens often with structures like linked lists or trees, that's one of the reasons why Nvidia is investing a lot of effort in improving [unified memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#um-unified-memory-programming-hd). If you can use that, and it doesn't decrease the performance of your application, it could save you a lot of trouble with problems like this.

Here is your example with the problems fixed:

```
class A {
public:
    int *s;
};

__global__ void MethodA(A *a) {
    printf("%d\n", a->s[2]);
    a->s[2] = 6;
}

int main() {
    A *a = new A();
    int asd[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    a->s = asd;

    A *a_with_d_s = new A();
    cudaMalloc(&(a_with_d_s->s), sizeof(int) * 5);
    cudaMemcpy(a_with_d_s->s, a->s, sizeof(int) * 5, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    A *d_a;
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, sizeof(A));
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a_with_d_s, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    MethodA << <1, 1 >> > (d_a);

    // note that if we call the following line, a->s will point to device
    // memory!
    //cudaMemcpy(a, d_a, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(a->s, a_with_d_s->s, sizeof(int) * 5, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%d\n", a->s[2]);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(a_with_d_s->s);

    delete(a);
    delete(a_with_d_s);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints out:

```
2
6
```

Comment: If i want to copy the whole object back, doing `cudaMemcpy(a, d_a, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);` this, won't work just as you said. It works if i copy it to another variable and than "merge" the two, but is there a better way?

Comment: I'd like to add to your answer too, because if `a` contains fields, other than `s` it won't copy those. copying those to `a_with_d_s` solves the problem.

Comment: @TóthBence I don't know of a better way then yours  - the problem here is that you need to do a deep copy of an object. This is not trivial even when you don't have distributed memory scenario to worry about. C++ tackles the problem by discouraging manually managing your memory and instead defines a set of standard containers (like `std::vector` and `std::array`) to use instead. However (AFAIK), the standard C++ library doesn't work in CUDA code. There is [thrust](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html), which you might be able to use instead, but I'm not an expert on it.

Comment: Thanks, i already read some articles about thrust but i don't think it could help in the copying.